# Can the Object class really be a lower bound?

Tags: java, generics

Why is the following legal when String & Integer are not super classes of Object ?

```
List<? super Object> mylist = new ArrayList<Object>();
mylist.add("Java"); // no compile error
mylist.add(2);
```

I'm aware that [wild card guidelines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) use lower bounded wild cards and super for 'out' variables but it seems that Object doesn't function as a 'lower bound' in this case.

Also is this the only way to allow addition of any type into a list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really simple. Remember that in Java, an instance of a subtype is also an instance of its supertypes.

Look at the signature of `add`

```
public boolean add(E e)
```

That means whatever you pass something whose type is `E` or any subtype of `E`.

You have a `List<? super Object>`. So you can pass to `myList.add()` anything whose type is `? super Object` (an unknown type which could be `Object` or supertype thereof) or any subtype thereof.

Is Integer a subtype of all types contained by `? super Object`? Of course. `Integer` is a subtype of `Object`, which is a subtype of all types contained by `? super Object` (of course, in this case, only `Object` satisfies this).

You're confusing the type parameter with the things you can pass to methods. The *type argument* of `List<? super Object>` is an unknown type that is a supertype of `Object`, so `Integer` or `String` cannot be the actual type parameter. In fact, in this case the only valid actual type argument would be `Object`. But what you're asking when you pass something to the method is, is the thing I'm passing a subtype? And the answer is yes.

Answer (score 3):

It's because Object is a superclass for Integer and String. You're interpreting the generic relationship the other way around.

**Edit**

Think about this situation:

```
List<? extends myClass> listOfMyClass = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

In this case, you'll end up with a list of `Object` type elements but that have to respect the restriction added by the declaration of the `listOfMyClass` list.

You'll be able to add any object that belongs to the `myClass` hierarchy to the list. The `ArrayList` that's implementing the `List` interface will hold (and return) `Object` type elements when requested.

Of course, you can define this:

```
List<? extends myClass> listOfMyClass = new ArrayList<mySuperClass>();
```

As you might now, the `ArrayList` must contain objects with the same type or a supertype of `myClass` and, in this case, that's the `mySuperClass`. This list will return `mySuperClass` objects qhen requested.

Taking `ClassX` as a class that does not belong to the mySuperClass hierarchy, the following line won't compile:

```
List<? extends myClass> listOfMyClass = new ArrayList<ClassX>();
```

That's because `ClassX` is not a superclass of `myClass`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html states "a lower bounded wildcard restricts the unknown type to be a specific type or a super type of that type"

Comment: It also states that "A lower bounded wildcard is expressed using the wildcard character ('?'), following by the super keyword, followed by its lower bound: <? super A>." Here, A is Object but I agree that calling A the lower bound when it is, in fact, a superclass can be misleading.

Comment: I don't agree that i'm interpreting the generic relationship incorrectly. What do you have to say to the answer provided by @Dancrumb ?

Comment: It's a valid answer, in line with what I'm saying. As he states, your list will hold objects and the wildcard will make sure those objects are subclasses of object. String and Integer are both subclasses of object. I'll edit my answer with an example of another case.

Comment: @sridhara There, I've edited my answer. Hope it helps to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it's confusing, but here's what's happening.

In this line of code:

```
List<? super Object> mylist...
```

You're saying that `myList` is a `List`, where each element can be of a type that is `Object` or a superclass of `Object`. However, you're only declaring the type of `myList` here.

What the wildcard does is restricts your implementation of `myList`.

Then, you do this:

```
List<? super Object> mylist = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

*Now* what you're doing is instantiating an `ArrayList<Object>`. Your lower bound wildcard is used to check that this is valid. It is valid, because `Object` matches `? super Object`. At this point, you have a `List<Object>` and your ensuing method calls are permitted.

Comment: The `new ArrayList<Object>` part has nothing to do with the question really. The same question could be asked with `List<? super Object> mylist = null;`

Comment: How can you add to a list without initialising ?

Comment: I guess the point is that `Object` is the only class that matches the wildcard `<? super Object>`